# Trouble creating a paragraph node

Tags: javascript, nodes

I can't get the second text node to appear

https://codepen.io/CusterMonroe/pen/QWLRqze

No error in console. The text node " Documents" just does not get printed to the screen. Wondering why. Thanks.

```
var newEm = document.createElement("em");
var text1 = document.createTextNode("Historic");

var newP = document.createElement("p");
var text2 = document.createTextNode(" Document");

newEm.appendChild(text1);
newP.appendChild(text2);
var phrase = newP.insertBefore(newEm,text2);

 document.getElementById("testBox").appendChild(phrase);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `insertBefore` is the inserted node, so you're only inserting `newEm`. Instead append the `newP`.

```js
var newEm = document.createElement("em");
var text1 = document.createTextNode("Historic");

var newP = document.createElement("p");
var text2 = document.createTextNode(" Document");

newEm.appendChild(text1);
newP.appendChild(text2);
var phrase = newP.insertBefore(newEm, text2);

document.body.appendChild(newP);
```

```css
#testBox {
  border: 2px black solid;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto 25px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div="testBox"></div>
```

I might write it to be a little more concise.

```js
var newP = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));

newP.appendChild(document.createElement("em"))
  .appendChild(document.createTextNode("Historic"));

newP.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Document"));
```

```css
#testBox {
  border: 2px black solid;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto 25px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div="testBox"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been working on that for a while, couldn't figure out what was going on.

Comment: You're welcome. It's usually the case that the element being inserted is the one returned, so that you can create it while inserting it, and still obtain a reference to it. My last example takes advantage of that.

Comment: Your revision to the code is good. My code was simply created for concept building, since I am new to nodes.